# How to check the current layout?

Tags: android, view

I have two layouts and I want to change from my first layout to the second layout through the back button, but I need to check the current layout, how can I do this?

I have done this right now:

```
View v;

@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        v.getRootView().getId();
        if(v==getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(id.mainlay)){
            setContentView(R.layout.quiz_layout);
        }

     }
```

Comment: can you explaing your question?

Comment: Are you trying to revert to the previous layout?  If so can you use finish() method?

Comment: want to get the currentView, which layout the user actually sees, so that I can make an if statement wheiter its the first or the second layout, to change what should happen when I press the back button on one of those two layouts.

Comment: I actually want to make a dialog when its in the main layout and i want to jump back to main layout when its in the quizlayout

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
View v; @Override public void onBackPressed() { super.onBackPressed(); ; if(v.getRootView().getId()==R.layout.anyLayout){ setContentView(R.layout.quiz_layout); } }
```

Comment: cant compare the v with the layout :/